# what is output of following code? if it is empty string then please explain why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I declare a string variable and want to access some characters with the help of slicing operators but it showing empty str as output.
please explain why it is showing empty.

I tried to print with different end index it works for all others but fails when end index becomes 0.

```py
s='0123456789'
print(s[2:-1:-1])
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: expected output: 210

Comment: for expected output, simply run "s[2::-1]"

Comment: I posted on my answer, mark as answered

Answer (score 1):

In Python slicing, `-1` means "the last element". So for a 10-character string, it's equivalent to `9`. And then since your step is `-1`, you are slicing in the wrong way, so the result becomes empty.

If you want `'210'`, you can go with `s[2::-1]`, although it's a bit inconvenient when your end is a variable. There are multiple workarounds, though, like `s[0:3][::-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

See:

```
>>> s='0123456789'
>>> print(s[2:-1:-1])

>>> print(s[-1:2:-1])
9876543
```

The reason that the first statement isn't printing anything is because the *start* is already less than the *end* - if you were to continue to step `-1`, you would go out of the bounds of the array. Keep in mind that `s[-1]` resolves to `s[len(s) - 1]`.

Or, in other words, if I told you to start at the second index of the array and go frontwards until you hit the last index of the array, it wouldn't make sense. After all, if you go frontwards, you're going towards the *front* of the array, not the *back*.

Meanwhile, if I switch those commands around - "start at the last index, and go frontwards until you hit the second index" - that makes perfect sense.

Comment: but if I want to go back/reverse direction/right to left then why it condition fails?

Comment: The code behind list slicing does this: (1) starts at `start` (the first argument); (2) checks which direction it's supposed to go based on the sign of `step` (the third argument); (3) goes `abs(step)` in that direction; (4) stops when it has passed `end` (the second argument). So if the step is negative, then *it's passed `end` as soon as it's started*. As a result, it returns immediately, thus producing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

First argument means start_index, second means end_index (empty means until end iteration), third is step.

Your expected output: 210

```
s='0123456789'
print(s[2::-1])
```

output:

```
210
```